# Usage of gdal utilities to subset from raster

Tags: raster, gdal, extents, subset

How to you use GDAL to subset a smaller raster from a bigger one given the bounding coordinates?

Comment: See http://gfoss.blogspot.it/2008/06/gdal-raster-data-tips-and-tricks.html  --> Extracting spatial subset (subregion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

```
gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry inraster.tif outraster.tif`
```

Or

```
gdal_translate -srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize inraster.tif outraster.tif
```

> `-projwin ulx uly lrx lry`:
>       Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying with the corners given in georeferenced coordinates.
>
> `-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize`:
>       Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on pixel/line location.

> EDIT: Can you subset a region from a vrt ?

```
gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry inraster.vrt outraster.tif
gdal_translate -of VRT -projwin ulx uly lrx lry inraster.tif outraster.vrt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++ coding in gdal , then yes, you can subset with VRTDataset(), here you can give your desired size of subset in vrtcreate(xsize,ysize) and then saving it with using createcopy().